# How to Fake Key Stroke For a Web Application?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

We have a web application that that works with user camera and keystrokes, collects data on the client side using JS. The data contains the users head movements captured by [headtracker.js](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/) and keystrokes that are captured as an onscreen test runs in realtime.

We are planning to write end to end test cases for this test flow and the first thing we plan to do is to mock live streaming using recorded videos which is supported by headtracker (it supports ogv, mp4 etc).

Our next challenge is to mock and supply keystrokes to the web application as the test proceeds. So, each action on the UI may (or may not) require a user action through a keystroke which we are planning to automate.

Or is there a tool or technology that allows us to create such a virtual environment which could provide us real time response?

I am able to provide more information as required.

Comment: Just use any testing framework you like and call the handlers for those keystrokes.

Comment: @Martin.kv If you are do edit a question or answer, please make sure you make all the necessary corrections, not just adding a tag when other things need to be fixed. Read the [When should I edit posts? section of the help center.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). As for a reliable web browser to driver it from tests, look at [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) (and the [PhantomJSDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/blob/master/binding/java/src/main/java/org/openqa/selenium/phantomjs/PhantomJSDriver.java) to control it).

Whatever you do, avoid IE at all cost when using Selenium. If you want to do unit testing with IE, buy a commercial testing framework.